# How to get triangle index using tree.any_intersection

Tags: cgal

Let's say we have a bunch of triangles 1,2,...,N, and a line segment. By making a tree, I want to get the intersection of the line segment with triangles and the index of the triangle that intersects the line segment (there is only one). How I call it from "intersection" below?

Thanks.

```
for (int i=0; i<NumTriangles; i++) {
    Point a(Triangles[i].vert1[0], Triangles[i].vert1[1], Triangles[i].vert1[2]);
    Point b(Triangles[i].vert2[0], Triangles[i].vert2[1], Triangles[i].vert2[2]);
    Point c(Triangles[i].vert3[0], Triangles[i].vert3[1], Triangles[i].vert3[2]);
    triangles.push_back(Triangle(a,b,c));
}
Tree tree(triangles.begin(),triangles.end());
Point a(0,0,0);
Point a(0,0,1);
Segment segment_query(a,b);
Segment_intersection intersection = tree.any_intersection(segment_query);
```

Answer (score 2):

Each triangle you put in the three is called a *primitive*. This primitive has a unique identifier (also known as *ID*) and a geometry (*datum*, here a triangle).

The type of the primitive ID is defined by the template parameter of the class [`CGAL::AABB_primitive`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/structCGAL_1_1AABB__primitive.html). If you are using the [`CGAL::AABB_triangle_primitive`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classCGAL_1_1AABB__triangle__primitive.html), which is just a simplified API around `CGAL:AABB_primitive`, then the ID is an iterator referring to the primitive within the range `triangles`.

The function [`any_intersection()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classCGAL_1_1AABB__tree.html#aabc82809b9ccc4ea39bab7ab3ae5ab00) returns an optional [object](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classCGAL_1_1AABB__tree.html#adcd65e098e0a79ce66a7df0097ba98aa) which is a pair that contains both the geometry of the intersection (as `first`) and the intersected primitive (as `second`), from which you can get the ID with the `id()` function.